# What is the proper way to disable NSTimer?

Tags: ios4, nstimer, invalidation

I am writing an app where the main view controller has several NSTimers that control different events.  This works well except for a few oddball cases where the timers don't seem to get disabled when I pop this main view controller off my navigation stack.

My question is this:  what is the proper way to invalidate or disable an NSTimer so that it doesn't get called again?

Right now, I instantiate an NSTimer like this:

```
alertViewTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(alertTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And I use this macro to invalidate the NSTimer:

```
#define TimerInvalidateAndNil(A) \
if(A != nil) \
{\
if([A isValid])\
{\
[A invalidate]; \
}\
A = nil; \
}
```

Comment: it's unneccessary to check for the time to be nil. Sending messages to nil is valid in Objective-C. Also, please note that NSTimers have nothing to do with your UI being popped/pooped/whatever. They do what you tell them to do and don't do bogus/magical state changes in the background (fortunately).

Comment: Ok.  Well the error I keep getting after I have popped the view controller that has the timer is "Message sent to deallocated instance" and it highlights a line where I call TimerInvalidateAndNil(timer) within the popped view controller.  This is also in a function that only gets called when a timer goes off and this function is supposed to then disable the timer.  Any ideas?

Comment: -invalidate releases the timer. If you didn't previously retain it, it will be deallocated thus the error message.

Comment: So are you saying that when I call alertViewTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerInterval:....], I should instead call alertViewTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerInterval:....] retain] and retain it?  Then invalidate will release it later?

Comment: No, you don't have to retain it. Just invalidate when it needs to be invalidated. If you want to track if it's valid or not, set it to NULL after invalidating and check for NULL afterwards.